# If magnetic field is an imaginary concept then why we say that they exert force?

Tags: electromagnetism

We say that magnetic field exerts a force but magnetic field is just an imaginary tool to determine magnitude and direction of force.

Comment: By this token everything in the world can be an imaginary tool to determine the magnitude and direction of force. In fact, why say that force isn't imaginary? Maybe only acceleration is real? Or maybe nothing is real? You'll probably have to motivate your question a little more

Comment: Welcome to Physics! It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking. Please add further information about the context so that other users will know exactly what the issue here is.

Answer (score 1):

Magnetic fields, just like electric fields and classical gravitational fields are real.

I suspect that what you refer to as the "imaginary tool" are the lines one draws to represent the field. That is also the case with electric fields and gravitational fields. The field doesn't really consist of lines. The lines are a qualitative tool to enable one to visualize the direction of the field at particular location by means of arrows on the field lines, from north to south pole for a magnetic field, as well as the relative strength of the field at a location based on the relative density of the lines at different locations for the same drawing.

Hope this helps.